# OutputStream on content URI

Tags: android, uri, android-workmanager

I have the content URI of a specific user selected image on which i want to open an InputStream, in order to get a Bitmap from that URI

When the user select the image, i take the persistable read and write permissions:

```kotlin
val flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
contentResolver?.takePersistableUriPermission(mediaUri, flags)
```

The content URI is in this format: `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A24`

The best solution to get this InputStream seems to be:

```kotlin
val inputFile = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputFile)
```

An error is thrown when running the second line of code:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A24: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Note that the URI seems to malformed in the error message

How can i get my InputStream ?

Addendum: I'm trying to get this InputStream in a Worker (androidx.work.CoroutineWorker).

User selects the image: https://github.com/ninjinskii/Cavity/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/louis/app/cavity/ui/addwine/FragmentAddWine.kt#L53

The image URI is stored in the DB: https://github.com/ninjinskii/Cavity/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/louis/app/cavity/ui/addwine/AddWineViewModel.kt#L86

User trigger the WorkManager in charge for image uploading:
https://github.com/ninjinskii/Cavity/blob/feature/backup-api/app/src/main/java/com/louis/app/cavity/ui/account/worker/UploadWorker.kt#L131

Comment: My guess is that you called `getPath()` on `mediaUri` at some point after your first code snippet and used that value to build `uri` in your second code snippet.

Comment: `OutputStream on content URI` There is nothing like that in your post.

Comment: It is pretty strange that BitmapFactory can determine a content scheme from an input stream. Hard to believe. That error is not produced by the code you posted.

Comment: I've updated my post to add some links

Comment: I am calling Uri.toString() to store it in the db, then when uploading the image im recreating the uri calling Uri.parse() on that string